# Facetime says connecting forever after buying a third iphone on the same account

Tags: facetime

I hope this is the right place to ask this, we have a iphone 4s and a iphone 5c. My dad recently bought another iPhone 5s, and now all 3 are on 1 apple ID. I shifted my mom's and sister's phone to another apple ID, to give dad exclusive access to his ID, however, when I try to facetime with any of the other phones, it says 'connecting' forever. I tried the advice [here](http://www.imore.com/having-trouble-imessage-or-facetime-ios-7-heres-how-fix-it), but to no avail.

Would appreciate any advice, should we just take it to the apple store?

Comment: explain how did you do the move. I assume the problem is there, with the devices that you moved from one to another account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nono.no need to the Apple store. You should make sure both you devices is up to date, I mean 7.1.2 as for now. Because the protocol of Facetime changes very often, sometimes old system can't get through. 
Maybe you should turn off and on your facetime after the software update .

Comment: I tried turning it off and on again. SHould I update all 3 phones to 7.1.2?

Comment: yes you must. after you upgrade try turn if off and on